# How do I putStrLn a Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString?

Tags: string, haskell, io, output, adhoc-polymorphism

I use `encode` (Haskell type via JSON to a string):

```
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson
```

The string is (according to an error message from the compiler): `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString`.

How do I putStrLn it?

#### put theoretically

What I'm in search for is a an ad-hoc polymorphic `putStrLn`, i.e., I'm looking for the proper instance of `putStrLn` semantics for a specific string-like type.

#### compiler messages

The compiler message if someone is interested:

```
valencies.lhs:182:22:
    Couldn't match type `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString'
                  with `[Char]'
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
    In the return type of a call of `encode'
    In the first argument of `putStrLn', namely `(encode CALL)'
    In the expression: putStrLn (encode CALL)
```

#### see also

Similar question, but with a bit different type: [How do I putStrLn a Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13205192/94687).

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on your `ByteString`. Does it really contain printable characters? What's the encoding on it? You can use `toString` from `utf8-string` if you know it contains valid UTF-8 and then pass it to `putStrLn`.

By the way, [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=ByteString+-%3E+String) is great for this type (hehe) of questions. Put a type in there and it will get you functions from Hackage with those types!

Answer (score 2):

You may use [string-class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/string-class) package, it has three options: `toString` function (defaults to utf-8), `fromLazyByteString` function, and `putStrLn` that works with all the types. Note, that you need to do:

```
import Prelude hiding (putStrLn)
import Data.String.Class (putStrLn)
```

Comment: That's smart! So, with `string-class` I don't have to explicitly choose the corresponding variant every time I write `putStrLn` , as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/28500229/94687 ?..

Comment: I had read about [-XOverloadedStrings](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.2/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#overloaded-strings). string-class is like taking the idea of `IsString` class further: with the `StringCells` and `StringRWIO` classes whose instances hold the dictionary of standard string functions and string IO actions for other string-like types....

Answer (score 0):

In this case, we have a `Lazy` variant, so we must use `Data.ByteString.Lazy.putStrLn`.

Note that the compiler gives an interesting warning:

```
In the use of `Data.ByteString.Lazy.putStrLn'
(imported from Data.ByteString.Lazy):
Deprecated: "Use Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8.putStrLn instead. (Functions that rely on ASCII encodings belong in Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8)"
```

Probably, if I want UTF-8 encoded strings, I should use another variant rather than the recommended `Char8` one. I'll try to find out this.

#### smart string-class

For a smart way, also have a look at `string-class` package mentioned in [another answer by Konstantine Rybnikov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28506036/94687).